# Use of "out of" with any words

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning

I have seen few words with word *out of* like

> Out of curiosity, Out of Loyalty

What does it mean? what are some other words we can make with this phrase.

Comment: What did your search for a definition for "out of" (as a phrase, not single words) return?

Comment: I am good understanding like _out of Home_, _out of town_ etc. but the given words seem different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*out of*" usually means "*because [of]*" in this context.

For a dictionary definition see [here near the bottom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of)

For example

> **Out of curiosity** why did you do {something}?

means

> Because I am curious, why did you do {something}?

In other words

> I'm not asking for any other reason but curiosity, why did you do {something}?

The speaker does not admit to having any other motive for asking.

Similarly "out of loyalty" means that the person is doing something because they are loyal rather than necessarily wanting to do it.

> I gave John an alibi **out of loyalty** to his father.

means

> Because I am loyal to his father I gave John an alibi.

As can be seen from the dictionary definition, "out of" has many other meanings and uses.